# Row greater than max size (8060) but I can't see why

Tags: sql-server, disk-space, storage, sparse-column

I have a table that has 483 columns.

A `date not null`, a `char(6) not null`, and then 481 x `float sparse null`.

By my maths, even if every sparse float is non-null, the row should still only be:

```
date: 3 bytes
char(6): 6 bytes
sparse float: 12 bytes x 481
sparse update overhead: 2 bytes x 483
= 6747 bytes and way below the limit of 8060 
    (even allowing lots for other random overheads)
```

In fact, the real-life row causing the issue still has 133 of the float columns as nulls and SQL Server claims this row has a row size of 8108 (and is too big).

What is the ghost that is taking up my row space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the ghost that is taking up my row space?

The table contains fixed-length columns which have been dropped. This could happen as part of a data conversion or through iterative development where the tool modifies the existing table structure as the design evolves.

As David Browne pointed out, this could also happen as a result of creating the (fixed length) `float` columns as *non-sparse null* initially, then altering them to *sparse*.

This **contradicts the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver16#restrictions-for-using-sparse-columns)** (emphasis added):

> - Changing a column from sparse to non-sparse, or non-sparse to sparse, requires changing the storage format of the column. The SQL Server Database Engine uses the following procedure to accomplish this change:
>
>   1. Adds a new column to the table in the new storage size and format.
>   2. For each row in the table, updates and copies the value stored in the old column to the new column.
>   3. Removes the old column from the table schema.
>   4. **Rebuilds the table (if there is no clustered index) or rebuilds the clustered index to reclaim space used by the old column**.

In fact, the structure is not rebuilt to reclaim space.

#### Example

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T 
(
    d date NOT NULL, 
    c char(6) NOT NULL
);
GO
-- Add a row
INSERT dbo.T (d, c) 
VALUES (CONVERT(date, GETUTCDATE()), 'abcdef');
GO
-- Add 481 float null columns
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG
        (
            CONCAT
            (
                CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'ALTER TABLE T ADD '),
                FORMAT(SV.number, '\f0'),
                N' float NULL;'
            ),
            SPACE(1)
        )
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SV.number)
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV  
    WHERE
        SV.[type] = N'P'
        AND SV.number BETWEEN 1 AND 481
);

EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

Alter the float columns to sparse:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT
        STRING_AGG
        (
            CONCAT
            (
                CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'ALTER TABLE dbo.T '),
                N'ALTER COLUMN ',
                FORMAT(SV.number, '\f0'),
                N' ADD SPARSE;'
            ),
            SPACE(1)
        )
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SV.number)
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV  
    WHERE
        SV.[type] = N'P'
        AND SV.number BETWEEN 1 AND 481
);

EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

Show the dropped columns using an undocumented system view:

```
SELECT 
    P.[partition_id],
    C.partition_column_id,
    C.max_inrow_length,
    C.leaf_offset
FROM sys.partitions AS P
JOIN sys.system_internals_partition_columns AS C
    ON C.[partition_id] = P.[partition_id]
WHERE
    P.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T', 'U')
    AND P.partition_number = 1
    AND C.is_dropped = 1
ORDER BY
    P.[partition_id], 
    C.partition_column_id;
```

First ten entries only shown for brevity:

| partition_id | partition_column_id | max_inrow_length | leaf_offset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108865 | 8 | 13 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108866 | 8 | 21 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108867 | 8 | 29 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108868 | 8 | 37 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108869 | 8 | 45 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108870 | 8 | 53 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108871 | 8 | 61 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108872 | 8 | 69 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108873 | 8 | 77 |
| 72057594129154048 | 67108874 | 8 | 85 |

Update the row with values for all but 133 float columns:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) =
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT
        (
            N'UPDATE t SET ',
            STRING_AGG
            (
                CONCAT
                (
                    FORMAT(SV.number, '\f0'),
                    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N' = RAND()')
                ),
                N','
            )
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SV.number)
        )
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV  
    WHERE
        SV.[type] = N'P'
        AND SV.number BETWEEN 1 AND 481 - 133
);

EXECUTE (@SQL);
```

The error message is:

```
Msg 511, Level 16, State 1
Cannot create a row of size 8108 which is greater than the allowable 
  maximum row size of 8060.
The statement has been terminated.
```

To remove the 'ghost' dropped fixed-length columns, you need to rebuild the table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T REBUILD;
```

The previous operation now succeeds.

[*db<>fiddle* demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nBIKZeVH)

---

Fixed-length columns cannot be cleaned up with `DBCC CLEANTABLE`.

Dropped variable-length columns do not cause a problem because SQL Server can clean them up or move them off-row to make space when adding a new sparse column.

Comment: Yes, absolutely they were created (via select into as shorthand) normal then switched to sparse. Alter table rebuild fixes my issue. I wish there was a way to make SQL server report what it thinks the breakdown of the row is! I will save your undocumented query sql for the future.